UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW on ContentFolder when attempting to create ContentDocument
Recently the primary admin user of a production org has intermittently different types of jobs and batches failing with the following error:

"First error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: 07H1r0000000C0cEAE"

The failing insert is of a ContentDocument or ContentVersion. The 07H1r0000000C0cEAE is a ContentFolder with its name being the Id of his User record. All existing 106 ContentFolders have a User ID as their name on an org with several thousands of Users. There is no Apex that would indicate where these folders come from or how they got their names, and I haven't found anything on this in the documentation. I suppose they get their names automatically assigned, when there is some necessity to create them for the API, but no Name is explicitly provided. What would be a typical situation where this happens? I'm Admin on this org (and on diverse related Sandboxes), but no ContentFolder has my User ID, although I test similar things on Sandboxes. CRM Content is not enabled and no ContentFolderLinks point to the ContentFolders, if this of any interest.
In case of the primary admin user, the ContentFolder has 511 601 ContentFolderMembers, which points at Ownership skew: There are indeed too many jobs making this user the Owner of a File. This needs to be addressed, even as the User has a Role on the very top of the hierarchy.
Though I don't see any type of sharing recalculation this would entail in this case. It looks like lock contention by a number of jobs trying to attach something to the same object. True? Is the number of ContentFolderMembers indeed unusually high?
The problem has been observed before (see here and here). Contrary to these I can't pinpoint the problem to a specific (ContentDocument) insert. A number of different batches, web hooks etc. are affected.
Any reference to helpful documentation welcome. There is so much to understand ContentDocument, ContentDocumentLink, ContentVersion - but ContentFolder information appears scarce and not interested in Users that actually would rather not want them!

I think the 106 ContentFolders correspond to each user's personal library, see Content Implementation Guide page 8.  However, I don't understand why that admin user's folder has 511K members.

@DavidCheng, many thanks for this feedback! I read an older version of this PDF years ago, but for some reason overlooked it when investigating the issue at hand. I think you are right and they represent personal libraries. The error has bugged us for about 2 hours on a single day and since not happened anymore, although nothing has changed on the org. A hiccup of the database?!
